# DNS CNAME from www to root still shows www

Tags: dns

Yesterday I bought a new domain for my website. I created a CNAME DNS entry from "www.mywebsite.com" to "mywebsite.com". So people who visit the website with www should be redirected to the root domain. But if I enter "www.mywebsite.com" in the browser and the website loads correctly but still shows "www.mywebsite.com" in the bar. I already used the dig command in the terminal and it shows the correct cname and then the correct resolution from "mywebsite.com" to the IP address. I am pretty new with DNS and don't know what I am doing wrong.

Apache Virtual Host Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    Redirect 301 / http://mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

CNAME is not a redirect. It's just another (canonical) name for the domain.

You need to configure a redirect within your webserver.

Comment: But if I don't create a CNAME from www to the root I can't open the website with "www.mywebsite.com"? Or ist that entry totally useless?

Comment: yes, of course, you need to set a CNAME or an A Record to the IP address of your server

Comment: I created a VirtualHost to redirect the www.mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com. When I try to open the website now it says "Load cannot follow more than 20 redirects."

Comment: There seems to be an error in your VirtualHost configuration. Maybe you can show us your config?

Comment: Edited my question with the Virtual Host config.